# Python - Count number of values in a column where another column in the data frame is null

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset `df`

```
   UniqueID Col1 Col2
0      1234    5  NaN
1      1235    3    4
2      1233  NaN    3
3      1111    3  NaN
```

I'd like to know the number of rows where `Col1` is not null and `Col2` is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(df.Col1.notnull() & df.Col2.isnull()).sum()

2
```

Answer (score 2):

By using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
In [451]: df.dropna(axis=0,how='any',subset=['Col1']).Col2.isnull().sum()
Out[451]: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd obviously go with [PiRSquared's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46122594/2137255).

If you, however, want to go something fancy with `query`, then use

```
In [430]: df.query('Col1 == Col1 & Col2 != Col2').shape[0]
Out[430]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, in your example 'nAn' is not a null.  So, let's replace that string with np.nan.

```
df = df.replace('nAn',pd.np.nan)

df.Col1.notnull().sum()
```

or

```
df.Col1.count() # Note: `count` ignores nulls where `size`, `shape`, and `len` do not.
3
```

And, use `isnull` to check for nulls explicityly:

```
df.Col2.isnull().sum()
2
```

Comment: I think, OP needs on both columns together, see PiRSquared's.

Comment: Ah.. will modify later